# Using 貴様 {きさま}​ as a joke?

Tags: pronouns, music

I already know that 貴様 {きさま} is a very rude, derogatory term in japanese, and is practically forbidden in real life situations.
However, I came across a song called キモチ by Mukai Shuutoku, and it contains the following verses :

> 貴様に伝えたい　/ 俺のこのキモチを

Here is a link for a live version of the song : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1BYZCU7Jxw

So I wondered if it was meant to be sarcastic, or provocative or some form of artistic license?

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/51582/meaning/m0u/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes using 貴様 can be a joke, but I believe it's not used as a joke here. Judging from the [whole lyrics](https://www.joysound.com/web/search/song/73521), I can say the lyricist used several "dirty words" intentionally for some reason.

- ヘンタイ
- 犬猫畜生
- ブチこむ

So this 貴様 is simply there to show the person's high pride or arrogant attitude. Such words frequently appear especially in heavy metal music.

By the way 貴様 used to be a respectful word in *archaic* Japanese, but you can forget it in this case. It's clearly meant to be dirty in this song.

Answer (score 2):

"貴様" is sometimes used in lyrics. In the Japanese Middle Ages "貴様" was used as a respectful form, actually "貴" means "distinction" and "様" means "Mr. or Sir."

So conversationally "貴様" is a very rude form.

> 貴様に何が分かるか！ I bet you'll never know!

However in the lyrics "貴様" is used indicating close relationship.

The most famous lyrics with "貴様" is "同期の桜" as "貴様と俺とは同期の桜."

They (貴様と俺) joined together with the military and "俺" call my best friend as "貴様" before the air tokko "特攻" mission.